Cannot press the button
The Resume button, shown in the image below, does not work. I can pause and unpause the game by pressing Escape, but when I'm trying to press the Resume button, nothing happens.
I have an Event System and with an Input Module on it.


My Hierarchy looks like this, and I don't have any errors in the Console.


The method Resume should be called, when the Resume button is pressed.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pause : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject menu;
    public GameObject resume;
    public GameObject quit;

    public bool isPaused;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        menu.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if ( Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (isPaused)
            {
                Resume();
            }
            else
            {
                PauseTheGame();
            }
        }

    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        menu.SetActive(false);
        isPaused = false;
        Debug.Log("Perfect");
    }

    public void PauseTheGame()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        menu.SetActive(true);
        isPaused = true;
    }
    public void Exit()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}

I was trying to change the code, but nothing works.

On a first look everything seems fine. If you debug your code, is the callback indeed triggered? (On clicking resume, does your code jump into the Resume() function?)

As anjelomerte has mentioned, the code looks fine. You said by clicking Resume button nothing happens. Please, define nothing. Is Resume method called, so is "Perfect" written in console? You also said you have an EventSystem, do you also have an Input Module on it? Please, attach the image to your question.

@sashok "Nothing" means that when I press the Resume button, the cursor disappears from the screen and I cannot interact with the buttons. But I can still press ESC to resume the game. And yes,  If the Resume method is called, The "perfect" label is displayed in the console. Also i've set up Input Module ( i didn't gave it), but my problem is still not solved.

@anjelomerte Yes, my code jump into the Resume() (Added the screenshot) in the main Massage.

@hijinxbassist This screenshot was taken after I tried all the Input Modules. That's not the problem. If you remove the second module, nothing will change.

if it says perfect .. then something else is wrong, what exactly are you expecting thats not happening

@hijinxbassist Input Modules for both old and new Input Systems can handle the interactions with the buttons. So if you have both of them, just one will be used.

@dmitryrubanov If your cursor disappears from the screen when pressing the button, you cannot really say that "nothing" happens. You must have an error in the console. Please, check it out.

@BugFinder it says "Perfect" only if I press ESC to unpause the game (I think my code works well, because I can unpause), something wrong with the Resume button. I can't click on it. I've set up pressed color to red and selected color to purple to check if i can interact with button, but when I direct the cursor on the button, it doesn't change color. I have event system in the hierarchy, Raycast Target on, but button still doesn't work

@sashok i don't have any errors in my console. I've added the screenshot of my console after i press the Resume button (The buttons are not named because I recreated them)

@dmitryrubanov So your cursor disappears when your press the Resume button, but you don't get any errors in the console? This is weird. You said you had set the pressed and selected colors, but in order it to change the color, you should change its Highlighted Color. Please, check it out.

Also, are you sure there is no Raycast targets which can block you from pressing the button? Could you, please, show us your hierarchy?

@sashok i've added my hierarchy. I have the raycast in both inventory and PlayerController scripts (if it matters), but I deactivated them. Also i changed Highlighted Color, but noting changes. I just can't use button. I don't see any Raycast Targets.

@dmitryrubanov Do you have the Raycast target enabled on the Pause Menu? If yes, what happens if you disable it?

@sashok i don't have enabled Raycast on the Pause menu. Pause menu is an Empty object that contains my images and texts of my menu.

@dmitryrubanov Alright, everything is indeed fine with your Event System. I strongly believe that you cannot click on your Resume button, because of any other Raycast target being above it.

Please, try to create an empty Button above all your objects and see whether you can click on it. If you can, try to reposition the Resume button or remove any objects which prevent it from become a target.
